# SQL, Query should show higher number than 2

Tags: sql

i have a task.

I need to select cr_number is higher than 2
I tried with where but it didn't show me expected results
My Query

```
SELECT
sup.sup_id,
sup.sup_name_en AS name,
COUNT ( sup_cr.sup_id ) AS cr_number
FROM t_sup_supplier AS sup
ON sup_cr.sup_id_from = sup.sup_id
GROUP BY sup.sup_id, sup.sup_name_en
```

My result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c640R.png)

Comment: Where `sup_cr` coming from ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `HAVING` :

```
SELECT sup.sup_id, sup.sup_name_en AS name, COUNT(sup_cr.sup_id) AS cr_number
FROM t_sup_supplier AS sup
ON sup_cr.sup_id_from = sup.sup_id
GROUP BY sup.sup_id, sup.sup_name_en
HAVING COUNT(sup_cr.sup_id) > 2;
```